# Iso_level3_shift key not working in Firefox (Linux)

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, keymap

Under Firefox (Firefox 3.6 and Iceweasel 10.0.9), my Iso_level3_shift key (= "Alt Gr" key) is not working. That means that on my azerty keyboard, I can't press some characters like @, |, and so on, what is pretty annoying (I have to copy/paste from another window to enter it in Firefox).

More information :

- This key is not working **ONLY in Firefox** (and in two different versions of Firefox), it works perfectly in another applications
- It doesn't work even with **no modules installed**
- It **works perfectly on another computers** with the same configuration (Debian testing, same keymap), and never worked on this computer (a MacBook Pro (I didn't choose ...))
- I use an `.Xmodmap` file, but it doesn't work even if I deactivate it (and I use the same file on another computers on which Firefox works fine)

Configuration :

- MacBook Pro 9.1 (mid-2012) with Debian testing (wheezy)
- Iceweasel 10.0.9 (tested also on Firefox 3.6.28)

Do you have any advices / insights on what could be causing the problem ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: I have the same problem but sometimes it works. I just don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for mi

```
setxkbmap -option lv3:rwin_switch
```

Found in https://askubuntu.com/questions/293560/mapped-keys-do-not-work-in-some-applications