# Xmodmap ignored in Firefox, revisited

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard, xorg

Related posts, but no solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386403/xmonad-xmodmap-changed-tab-to-alt-gr-but-it-doesnt-work-on-firefox-or-thunderbi
[Iso_level3_shift key not working in Firefox (Linux)](https://superuser.com/questions/489917/iso-level3-shift-key-not-working-in-firefox-linux)

I have the following ~/.Xmodmap

```
keycode 13 = 4 currency 4 currency dollar onequarter dollar
keycode 16 = 7 slash 7 slash braceleft division braceleft
keycode 21 = backslash dead_grave backslash dead_grave dead_acute notsign       dead_acute
keycode 22 = BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace Delete NoSymbol            Terminate_Server NoSymbol NoSymbol Terminate_Server BackSpace BackSpace         NoSymbol NoSymbol Terminate_Server
keycode 51 = apostrophe asterisk apostrophe asterisk dead_doubleacute multiply  dead_doubleacute
keycode 134 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
```

This works fine (xterm, Libreoffice, etc), except in Firefox.

Only my mapping of ISO_Level3_Shift seems to be affected. I use this to produce keys like curly brackets and the dollar sign.

I do have in my /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/30-keyboard.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "evdev keyboard catchall"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "XkbModel" "asus_laptop"
    Option "XkbVariant" "intl"
    Option "XkbLayout" "no"
EndSection
```

I've looked in my Xorg.log.0, and I can see that the "intl" parameter apparently is successfully parsed:

```
[   429.097] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   429.097] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   429.097] (**) Option "xkb_model" "asus_laptop"
[   429.097] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "no"
[   429.097] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
```

There are no warnings or errors in my Xorg.log.0, except:

```
[   429.080] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   429.080] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   429.080] (**) Option "xkb_model" "asus_laptop"
[   429.080] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "no"
[   429.080] (**) Option "xkb_variant" "intl"
[   429.087] (EE) Error loading keymap /var/lib/xkb/server-0.xkm
[   429.087] (EE) XKB: Failed to load keymap. Loading default keymap instead.
```

Since the identifier is evdev I believe it attempts to apply these rules even to the power button device and fails. However I don't believe this is relevant to the keyboard, which gets treated as a different device; and there are no errors nor warnings associated with that device.

This is a Macbook Pro, it is running Gentoo.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this issue? I have the same in FF and Thunderbird on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Same in lubuntu 20.04